# Cual es la forma correcta de guardar resultados de una funcion en un dataframe con python

Tags: python, function

Estoy trabajando con la información de un gran premio de formula 1, uso una función que calcula el tiempo que tarda cada piloto en los boxes durante la carrera. De esta forma mi función es iterable para cada uno de los pilotos. Mi pregunta es, cuál es la forma más eficiente de guardar los resultados computados en un dataframe si la función es iterable?

Hasta ahora he conseguido que la función haga lo que deba de hacer, pero al momento de intentar escribir los resultados para todos los pilotos en un solo dataframe, solo consigo el resultado del último piloto. Gracias de antemano.

EDIT. Mi funcion luce asi:

```
def desplazamiento(dfT, t_step, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y']):


    N = int(len(dfT))
    max_time = np.float(N*(q))   
    frames = np.float(max_time/N)
    t_step = frames

    data = pd.DataFrame({'N':[N],'max_time':[max_time],'frames':[frames]})
    tau = t.copy()
    shifts = np.divide(tau,t_step).astype(float)
    msds_sum = np.zeros(shifts.size)
    delta_inv = np.arange(N)
    delta = delta_inv[N-1::-1]




    for i, shift in enumerate(np.round(shifts,0)):
        diffs = dfT[coords] - dfT[coords].shift(-shift)
        sqdist = np.square(diffs).sum(axis=1)
        msds_sum[i] = sqdist.sum()
        msd = np.divide(msds_sum,delta)


    msds = pd.DataFrame({'msd':msd})
    return msds

Pilots = [1,22,4,7,44,22,8,10,99,00,56,77]   
for j in Pilots:

    dfk = df2.loc[j] 
    dfT = dfk.iloc[:5]

    msd = desplazamiento(dfT, t_step, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y'])    
    print(msd)
```

y la dataframe que quiero analizar seria informacion GPS con datos de coordenadas para cada piloto:

```
                POSITION_X  POSITION_Y  POSITION_T
    Pilots                                    
    1              1.649       0.368       0.042
    1              1.576       0.371       0.084
    1              1.651       0.313       0.126
    1              1.723       0.340       0.168
    1              1.381       0.355       0.210
    1              1.324       0.469       0.252
   44              1.202       0.540       0.294
   44              1.323       0.427       0.336
   44              1.197       0.599       0.420
   44              1.327       0.519       0.462
   44              1.450       0.595       0.504
   44              1.684       0.577       0.546
   44              1.792       0.678       0.588
    5              1.852       0.906       0.630
    5              1.762       0.827       0.672
    5              1.735       0.961       0.714
    5              1.657       1.083       0.756
    5              1.897       1.074       0.798
    5              1.961       1.126       0.840
    5              2.067       1.167       0.882
    5              2.046       1.267       0.966
    5              1.922       1.228       1.008
    5              1.992       1.230       1.050
    5              1.945       1.198       1.092
    5              2.002       1.224       1.134
    5              1.866       1.213       1.176
    5              1.851       1.482       1.218
    5              1.600       1.724       1.260
    5              1.681       2.064       1.302
```

Comment: Hola @Jonathan, puedes poner algún extracto de tu código para entender mejor tu pregunta? y así ver lo que has hecho y ver si hay que modificar, eliminar o añadir algo más a tu código

Comment: La funcion corta  los datos y usa los primero 5 valores para cada piloto y las primeras 5 coordenadas las usa para computar con la funcion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a darte una idea conceptual de una posible solución a tu pregunta, al no tener los datos reales, vamos a jugar con un ejemplo. Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente `Dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1000], 'b': [200, 2000], 'c': [300, 3000]})
df

      a     b     c
0   100   200   300
1  1000  2000  3000
```

Y como en tu pregunta, queremos aplicar una función determinada para generar una nueva columna que vamos a definir a modo de ejemplo como: la suma de la columna `b` menos cada elemento de la columna `a` mas cada elemento de la columna `c`.

La función podría ser algo así:

```
def funcion(row, df):
    return df["b"].sum() - row[0] + row[2]
```

Aplicar esta función sobre el dataframe y generar una nueva columna puede hacerse así:

```
df['d'] = df.apply(funcion, df=df, axis=1)
```

El resultado:

```
      a     b     c     d
0   100   200   300  2400 # 2200 - 100 + 300
1  1000  2000  3000  4200 # 2200 - 1000 + 3000
```

En tu código, entiendo, debieras rediseñar `desplazamiento` para que reciba el `dataframe` completo, tal como lo hago en mi ejemplo, y dentro de la función hagas la búsqueda de las 5 lecturas por `Piloto` y el resto de los cálculos, lo importante es que esta función debiera retornar el valor que queremos para la celda puntual del `dataframe`.

Comment: Se agradece mucho que te tomes el tiempo de ver como funciona mi codigo, gracias a tu ejemplo puedo ver a grandes rasgos como alojar los resultados en mi dataframe